# dask using delayed to construct a list of functions but specify the number of process to use

Tags: python, dask

I have a function to do computation, here is a simple one as an example,

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

And then I execute this function 100 times in a embarrassingly parallel way,

```
output = [delayed(add)(i,i+1) for i in range(100)]
compute(*output)
```

My question is the above code will start 100 process? If so, is there a way to make it start say 10 process, so to reduce the time to start process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `get` for dask delayed is a thread pool with as many threads as you have cores.

You can use a different `get` (rather than the threaded one) as well as specify `get` parameters via `compute`. To use a thread pool with 10 threads you might do `dask.compute(*output, num_workers=10)`. To use the `multiprocessing` module based get with 10 workers, you might do `dask.compute(*output, get=dask.multiprocessing.get, num_workers=10)`. (Note that the multiprocessing module, on which `dask.multiprocessing` is based, is not the biggest gem in the stdlib. Dask's use is probably a rare one that should mostly work if you use it in a really plain way, but if I needed process-based parallelism with dask, I'd be quick to use [Distributed](https://distributed.readthedocs.io), even on a single host.)

Answer (score 2):

The default schedulers start up thread pools or process pools with the same number of threads/processes as you have logical cores on your machine (though this is configurable).  Dask won't spin up as many processes as you have tasks; as you suggest, this would be very inefficient.

You can learn a bit more about Dask's schedulers at [this doc page](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html).